# Splunk search query to create a table from JSON search result

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am relatively new to Splunk search and I am trying to build a table from my splunk search results.

Can someone please help me to build a table using following JSON

My search results  as follows

```
{ [-]
   docker: { [+]
   }
   kubernetes: { [+]
   }
   log: LOGGER {"name":"some text here","pathname":"/some/path","timestamp":"2023-05-03T20:35:06Z","action":"pageview","payload":{"category":"cloths","country":"US","appEnv":"production"},"uID":"0023493543"}
   stream: stdout
}
```

raw text:

```
{
  "stream": "stdout",
  "log": "LOGGER {\"name\":\"Some text here\",\"pathname\":\"/some/path\",\"timestamp\":\"2023-05-04T10:44:05Z\",\"action\":\"pageview\",\"payload\":{\"category\":\"cloths\",\"country\":\"US\",\"appEnv\":\"production\"},\"uID\":\"0023493543\"}",
  "docker": { "container_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx" },
  "kubernetes": {
    "container_name": "xxxxxx",
    .....
    },
    "labels": {
      .....
    },
    "namespace_id": "xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx",
    "namespace_labels": {
      "application-id": "48928423",
      "namespace": "849328932-243232xxxx",
        ........    }
  }
}
```

From this I would like draw the table as

```
| uID | pathname | category | eventName | country | timestamp |
| 0023493543   | /some/path   | cloths | some text here | US |
| ----   | ----   | ----   | ----   | ----   | ----   |
```

I have tried building table using spath, eval, extract commands but none of tries gives me any desired result. If its a plain JSON object in log field, I managed to build a query for few selected fields, but as its a text String and JSON in it, I am not sure, how to extract my fields.

I am expecting a table as shown above, later I can modify query for my complex result.

Update:

I tried following query,

```
BASE SEARCH | spath path=log | rex field=_raw max_match=0 "name\W+(?<name>[^\"]+)" | rex field=_raw max_match=0 "pathname\W+(?<pathname>[^\"]+)" | rex field=_raw max_match=0 "timestamp\W+(?<timestamp>[^\"]+)" | rex field=_raw max_match=0 "category\W+(?<category>[^\"]+)" | rex field=_raw max_match=0 "country\W+(?<country>[^\"]+)" | rex field=_raw max_match=0 "uID\W+(?<uID>\w+)" | table uID, pathname, category, name, country, timestamp
```

which gives me desired result, except name field. It gives me additional text as

```
some text here\
some/path
....
```

but I need only `some text here`

Comment: Please edit the question to include the raw data.

Comment: @RichG, I have added raw text now, thanks for your time

Comment: The problem is that `name` will math pathname and name so you are getting both results in name.  If you change the rex to `| rex field=log max_match=0 "\"name\W+(?<name>[^\"]+)"` then you will only find `name`

Answer (score 0):

Splunk's JSON parser doesn't like the sample data so the `spath` command can't be used to extract the desired fields.  It *can* be used to extract the log field then the extract command can break out the remaining fields.

````
| makeresults | eval _raw="{
  \"stream\": \"stdout\",
  \"log\": \"LOGGER {\\\"name\\\":\\\"Some text here\\\",\\\"pathname\\\":\\\"/some/path\\\",\\\"timestamp\\\":\\\"2023-05-04T10:44:05Z\\\",\\\"action\\\":\\\"pageview\\\",\\\"payload\\\":{\\\"category\\\":\\\"cloths\\\",\\\"country\\\":\\\"US\\\",\\\"appEnv\\\":\\\"production\\\"},\\\"uID\\\":\\\"0023493543\\\"}\",
  \"docker\": { \"container_id\": \"xxxxxxxxxxxx\" },
  \"kubernetes\": {
    \"container_name\": \"xxxxxx\"
    },
    \"labels\": {
      \"foo\": \"bar\"
    },
    \"namespace_id\": \"xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx\",
    \"namespace_labels\": {
      \"application-id\": \"48928423\",
      \"namespace\": \"849328932-243232xxxx\"
    }
  }
}"
``` Above created test data.  Delete IRL ```
``` Parse the JSON as much as we can ```
| spath
``` Replace _raw with log for field extraction ```
| eval _raw=log
``` Extract fields from log ```
| extract pairdelim=",}" kvdelim=":"
| table uID pathname category eventName country timestamp
````

Note, however, the desired category and eventName fields are not present in the sample event so they don't display in the output.